# Clicking on submit button on pop up submit form using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Scenario- https://www.cleartrip.com/ site. Click on Your Trips and then click on Sign In option. A pop up appears for sign In details. Need to click on sign In button. I tried everything- normal click, window handle, alert and frames. Not able to click on it. Can some one help me here?

Answer (score 1):

When you got the pop up showing, you will want to switch to the pop up iFrame:

In python:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("modal_window")
```

In Java:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("modal_window")
```

Where "modal_window" is the id of the iFrame you want to switch on to.

Then you can do your submit button click function:

```
driver.find_element_by_css("signInButton").click()
```